# js file and css files are not loaded correctly after the url routing in asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to implement the urlrouting for asp.net webforms. My problem is all the js file and the css files not loaded on the page because it cannot refer to the correct path.

I've refer the js on the my master page as shown below.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>


 <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Could you please help me for a solution.

Comment: you need to change your rewriting rules to exclude things like js and css

Answer (score 2):

you can use the [`Page.ResolveUrl(String relativeUrl)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

`Page.ResolveUrl("...")` will generate an absolute path out of an relative one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='@Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")' charset="utf-8"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")%>' charset="utf-8"></script>
```

depending on if you're using [`razor markup`](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/razor_intro.asp) or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct format to call your JQuery script with. The '~' refers to the root directory. So assuming your script is in this location, it should work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

However, the line above it attempts to load the same script, but does not include the '~' character.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

...and you aren't attempting loading any CSS files. So delete the first line, and then add the correct tags to load your CSS files.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/mystyle.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Only use `/` Because it means root of the site. (if `Scripts` dir under your root)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: This don't work in every case... imagine he will publish the homepage in a subfolder i.E.: **`http://foo.com/bar/`**. So if he uses **`/`** the browser would look for the scripts under **`http://foo.com`** instead of **`http://foo.com/bar/`**